# VideoCapture obj not reading in python (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: opencv, python

I'm trying to write to a .mp4 file (4K) with Opencv in Python. (Ubuntu 20.04) 
Below is the code I've been working on:

```
cap = VideoCapture(video_path)
is_opened = cap.isOpened() # returns True
width, height = int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4)) # returns correct values
ret, frame = cap.read() # returns False, None respectively
```

The video opens but cap.read() refuses to work. I've tried it with other types of videos and it does work. A specific codec maybe? (4K + mp4)  doesn't work.

Additionally, I have three systems all running Ubuntu 20.04 with different packages installed.
The above symptoms does not appear only on one system. I tried syncing the Python installations as much as possible but no luck. I don't know what I'm missing (or what I installed, causing the above issue).

Any suggestions, reponse is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: `cap.read() refuses to work`what kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to write to a .mp4 file (4K) with Opencv in Python.

I would like to emphasize the two points

- 1. Initializing `fourcc` parameter correctly

  - ```py
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc("mp4v")
    ```
- 2. Initializing `VideoWriter` correctly

  - The width and height parameters of the `VideoWriter` must be same as the current frame.

    - If you are reading from an input video, you can get the width and height like:

      - ```py
        _, example_frame = cap.read()
        (h, w) = example_frame.shape[:2]
        ```
      - But if you are planning resizing the frames, then set width and height to the new size
  - If you are processing color image? If so you should set `isColor` to True, False otherwise.
  - ```py
    output = "output.mp4"
    fps = 24
    writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output, fourcc,
                             (w, h), isColor=True)
    ```

Here is an example code:

---

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("input.mp4")
_, example_frame = cap.read()
(h, w) = example_frame.shape[:2]
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
fps = 24
output = "output.mp4"
writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output, fourcc, fps, (w, h), isColor=True)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        writer.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cap.release()
writer.release()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We are assuming codec issues, just decided to skip the frames where it can't read. Still couldn't figure out why results vary but thanks again for the insight.

Comment: What do you mean by "results vary"?

Comment: That opencv shows different symptoms for a same video in different systems

Comment: Are you using the same version for different systems? And ehat is your opencv version? Just `print(cv2.__version__)`

Comment: All ubuntu 20.04, all 4.5.1

Comment: But is 4.5.1 stable version? I think it is still in `dev`Maybe using 4.4.0 will solve the problem.

Comment: Will try. Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem with .mp4 on Ubuntu 20.04. So far haven't found the solution.